# Behavior of mark tag with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I use flexbox to deal with horizontal and vertical alignment of a text in a div.
I want to use `mark` tag to highlight searched text in it but the behaviour is not what i expect : the text in the mark tag is detached from the word it belongs to.
Here is the sample code and picture :

```
<div class="cell">Bouclage de ceinture conducteur et p<mark>ass</mark>agers</div>
```

```
.cell {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 15em;
}
```

[Result and expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWwUM.png)

I want to keep flex display, do you have any idea how to solve this issue ? Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 2):

`align-items` should be 'start' instead of 'left' and add `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```
.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: start;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 15em;
}
```

[Stackblitz link for working solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-usqhc7?file=style.css)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With `flex-wrap: wrap` it is better but the word "passagers" is cut ('p' is alone at the end of the first row). Is there any way to keep the word complete ?

Comment: If that is the case, then you might need do follow few more additional steps. I have updated stackblitz link, you can have a look